# Is it possible to navigate through page by navbar without page refresh with Laravel Livewire and AlpineJS?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-livewire-wireclick

I am just wondering whether it's possible to navigate through navigation without **any page refresh** using Laravel Livewire and AlpineJS? I also want to keep the state of the clicked link of the navbar, so I can change it's color.
Thanks

Comment: You mean like SPA ?

Comment: Hi @xenooooo, yes exactly... as you know from reactjs or vuejs. Switching from the HomePage to the ContactPage for example without reloading everything.

Comment: run event or run function with wire:init | wire:click  ,... in livewire load data & render
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js

Comment: worth mentioning one of the features for livewire v3 (release date unknown) is `wire:navigate` for out of the box SPA style navigation

Comment: @SlateEntropy Ah, cool. great to know. Unfortunately, we are still at Livewire v2 :(

Comment: Hi @MahdiBagheriVarnosfatherani,
thanks for your reply.  What would you say to the other answer that Hefaz posted? I followed his advice and it works great so far.

Comment: @codingIsLove good . sample : 
in php use : `
    public $time; public function loadTime(){
        $this->time = date('H:i:s');
    }` , 
in blade use : `<div wire:init="loadTime">
    {{$time}}
    <button style="padding: 25px;" wire:click="loadTime">
        Update Time
    </button>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed. Livewire v3 has just been released and it includes that ability:

> Livewire offers a single page application experience via a simple attribute you can add to links in your application: wire:navigate.

For example:

```html
<nav>
    <a href="/" wire:navigate>Dashboard</a>
    <a href="/posts" wire:navigate>Posts</a>
    <a href="/users" wire:navigate>Users</a>
</nav>
```

For more, check out:

https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/navigate